# How do I get drawn objects to appear over images using HTML5 Canvas and JavaScript?

Tags: html, canvas

I'm wondering if anyone can help me figure out how to draw objects over images using HTML5 Canvas and JavaScript?

I've written an example to show my problem below (as long as you have an image called choc.jpg available it should work). I'd like the banana object to appear over the JPEG but it doesn't. I'm a newbie to HTML5 and canvas and would really appreciate being pointed in the right direction.
Thanks so much for your help!

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<script>

window.onload=function() {
var testcanvas=document.getElementById("bananaDesign");
var testcontext=testcanvas.getContext('2d');

//set a background image
/* if I comment out this section no image appears and the banana gets drawn. How do I get banana to go over image? */

var importedImg = new Image();
importedImg.src = 'pictures/choc.JPG';
importedImg.onload = function(){
testcontext.drawImage(importedImg, 10, 10);
};


//draw a banana
testcontext.fillStyle = "#FFA824";
testcontext.beginPath();
testcontext.moveTo(62,20);
testcontext.lineTo(80,20); //2
testcontext.lineTo(80,30); //3
testcontext.lineTo(90,50); //4
testcontext.lineTo(80,85); //5
testcontext.lineTo(45,95); //6
testcontext.lineTo(40,80); //7
testcontext.lineTo(60,60); //8
testcontext.lineTo(60,30); //9
testcontext.fill();
}

</script>


<canvas id="bananaDesign" width="500" height="600" style="border: 5px red solid">
<p>Your browser does not display HTML5 canvas. Please update to view this design.</p>
</canvas>
```

Answer (score 1):

The image is loaded asynchronously so it is actually drawn to the canvas after you've drawn the banana (and therefore over it). A quick fix would be to move your banana draw code into your image load handler, after you've drawn the image to canvas (see http://jsfiddle.net/5pGqV/, in retrospect the background image I chose wasn't ideal ;)):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<script>

    window.onload=function() {
        var testcanvas=document.getElementById("bananaDesign");
        var testcontext=testcanvas.getContext('2d');

        //set a background image
        /* if I comment out this section no image appears and the banana gets drawn. How do I get banana to go over image? */

        var importedImg = new Image();
        importedImg.src = 'pictures/choc.JPG';
        importedImg.onload = function(){

            //draw the loaded image to canvas first
            testcontext.drawImage(importedImg, 10, 10);

            //now draw a banana on top
            testcontext.fillStyle = "#FFA824";
            testcontext.beginPath();
            testcontext.moveTo(62,20);
            testcontext.lineTo(80,20); //2
            testcontext.lineTo(80,30); //3
            testcontext.lineTo(90,50); //4
            testcontext.lineTo(80,85); //5
            testcontext.lineTo(45,95); //6
            testcontext.lineTo(40,80); //7
            testcontext.lineTo(60,60); //8
            testcontext.lineTo(60,30); //9
            testcontext.fill();
        }; 
    }

</script>


<canvas id="bananaDesign" width="500" height="600" style="border: 5px red solid">
<p>Your browser does not display HTML5 canvas. Please update to view this design.</p>
</canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and giving me an alternative solution :-) This worked great!

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure the **globalCompositeOperation** attribute in context.
In your case set value to **'destination-over'** to draw over the image.
Here is list of all possible values http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#dom-context-2d-globalcompositeoperation.

Example with your code http://jsfiddle.net/gU4xc/

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer, it was exactly what I was after and also pointing me in the right to direction so I can better understand compositing. Very much appreciated!